# Проблема 1 писателя, многих читателей. Многопоточность C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, visual-c++, mutex, condition-variable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть поток-писатель, есть много потоков читателей. Вопрос в том, как реализовать ситуацию, когда поток-писатель пишет/обновляет данные в некотором поле, затем ждет, пока все читатели обработают эти данные (в этот момент писатель может рассчитывать обновление данных), когда они обработают, соответственно читатели НЕ пытаются повторно обработать уже обработанные данные, а ждут пока писатель обновит данные. Затем писатель сигналит читателям, что данные обновлены и те принимаются за работу.

Используется C++, MS VS 15/17, многопоточность стандартной библиотеки.

Пока моя идея сводится к использованию mutex (?, что если всех этих потоков много ~100000, нет ли ограничений на кол-во мьютексов) и condition variable. Вероятно, есть другое наиболее оптимальное решение и готовое.

Comment: Используйте [pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx). Pipes позволяет писать / читать любому к-ву потоков

Comment: nick_n_a, а pipes в стандартной библиотеке есть? как они там называются?

Comment: А зачем Вам много мьютексов? Одного не хватит?

Comment: Поставьте мутекс/семафор, где писатель записывает что 1 (или n) можно прочесть, а читатели убирают признак (уменьшают n).

Comment: ixSci, извиняюсь, неточно написал - каждый писатель одновременно и читатель других. Т.е. в каждом потоке выполняется и читательская и писательская функция - память у всех своя, мьютексы тоже. Потоков много - мьютексов тоже много потребуется.

Comment: Вы бы схему привели в вопросе, а то пока малопонятно, что там у Вас происходит. Схему и пример работы.

Comment: Ваша задача похожа на стек или на LIFO стек с блокировкой (concurent List stack или подобное). Такие готовые решения, думаю, можно найти.

Comment: ixSci, добавил схему действия во времени

Comment: Чтобы пользователь получил уведомление нужно использовать `@`, к примеру `@ixSci`, по другому не получит. Что касается схемы — не помогла она в понимании. Я по-прежнему не вижу откуда у Вас берётся много писателей и в схеме и в описании он только один. Для всего этого достаточно одного мьютекса и одной conditional_variable.

Comment: Приведите пример, нормальный, лучше кодом, чтобы было понятно. Сведите проблему к минимуму — по другому Вам никто не поможет.

Comment: Почитайте/поищите многозадачные очереди (concurent list / stack). Поищите `pipe` класс. Тут два решения, либо очередь либо pipe канал.

Comment: ixSci, да, в схеме на картинке один писатель и три читателя. Это просто часть системы. В системе в общем писатель читает данные у других писателей, а каждый читатель пишет, и это читают другие читатели. Т. е. каждый модуль системы одновременно и читатель и писатель. Здесь я привел "вырванный" кусок без чтения писателем и письма читателей. И пишут/читают они не друг у друга, а у других (каскадом), циклов нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если рассматривать только приведенный Вами кусок общей схемы с 1 писателем и несколькими читателями, то Вам подойдет для решения *блокировка чтения-записи*, суть ее в следующем :

- только 1 поток может захватить ее на запись, все остальные в это
  время ждут;
- на чтение ее могут захватить сразу несколько потоков, и читать не
  мешая друг другу;
- обычно приоритет "писателей" выше, что не дает читателям захватить
  блокировку навечно (но тут уже могут быть нюансы, надо реализацию
  смотреть).

Я пользовалась этим примитивом из библиотеки pthread, однако это подойдет только для Unix. Для Win можно посмотреть примеры использования boost::shared_mutex [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6450579), (вроде он появился и в 17 стандарте), или класс ReaderWriterLock [тут](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: А можете дать пример на задачу, в которой приоритет писателей каким-то образом установлен выше? Сейчас решаю эту задачу с использованием shared_mutex, и приоритет нужен не на уровне потоков (native_handle() и ко.), а на уровне разделения ресурса.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727684/Использование-stdshared-mutex-и-проблема-обделения-писателя/727735#727735 - вот мой вопрос по данной теме