# Использование std::shared_mutex и проблема "обделения" писателя

Tags: c++, mutex, c++17, shared-mutex

Допустим, есть несколько читателей и один писатель, которые имеют общий ресурс, контролируемый посредством `std::shared_mutex`. Как быть в ситуации, когда читатели читают ресурс не одновременно, а, скажем, по очереди, т.ч. мьютекс всегда удерживается через `std::shared_lock<>()`, и писатель не может записать новые данные в ресурс, т.е. не может пробиться через инструкцию `std::unique_lock<>`?

Тут приходит на ум логика решения, что попытка захвата мьютекса писателем должна иметь более высокий приоритет, чем у читателей, т.е. когда писатель хочет что-то записать - он оставляет "заявление", т.ч. никакие читатели не могут сделать `shared_lock`, а те, что уже сделали - доделывают свою работу и ожидают обновлений со стороны писателя. Когда писатель обновит данные - может сделать `notify_all()` через `condition_variable`, к примеру.

Не вполне понимаю, как реализовать "приоритет захвата" в коде + может имеются другие решения данной проблемы не через `std::shared_mutex`?

P.S. Натолкнулся на описание в стандартах алгоритма Терехова, в котором говорится о прохождении читателей/писателей через двое входов, на основе которых выставляется приоритет. Но не совсем его понял. А именно, пройдет ли писатель первый вход, когда на втором есть читатели и, если так, то не смогут ли новые читатели зайти на вход 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, как с приоритетами, а идея двух входов довольно очевидна.

Все делают эксклюзивный lock на `E1`. Получив его, читатели делают shared lock на `E2`, а писатели эксклюзивный. Получив lock на `E2` и читатели и писатель *тут же* освобождают lock на `E1`.

Таким образом, писатель прошедший `E1` будет блокировать всех пришедших после него читателей до тех пор, пока последний из совместно использующих `E2` читатель не освободит `E2`.

Comment: 1) «писатель прошедший E1 будет блокировать всех пришедших после него читателей» - можете поподробнее разъяснить, на каких условиях писатель проходит Е1?

Comment: 2) «последний из совместно использующих Е2 читатель не освободит Е2» - видимо, подразумевался писатель

Comment: 3) извиняюсь за потенциаально глупый вопрос, но этот механизм с Е1 и Е2 уже встроен в реализацию std::shared_mutex в 17 стандарте? Или надо этот алгоритм руками доделывать?

Comment: @I.S.M., не знаю, как там внутри в крестах реализовано, а на остальное попробую вечером вам ответить (сейчас занят)

Comment: @I.S.M.,  поясняю. 1) Писатель проходит `E1` точно так же, как и читатели, т.е. получив exclusive lock на E1; 2) Если  при попытке получить exclusive lock на `E2` тот занят предыдущим писателем (он в  рассматриваемый момент имеет **exclusive lock на E2**) , то ждем освобождения `E2` этим писателем (новый писатель продолжает удерживать `E1`), если `E2` удерживают один или *несколько* читателей (у них **shared lock на E2**), то ждем пока все они не освободят `E2`

Comment: Так, разобрался. А как понять, в какой момент писатель получит exclusive_lock на Е1, если у нас одновременно с ним еще несколько других пытаются его получить? Система отслеживает как-то кто в какой момент времени вызвал lock-функцию - и кто раньше, тому и доступ? Как строится очередь доступа через нескольких exclusive_lock, т.е. если у нас несколько заблокированных потоков ожидает? Просто, если не по времени вызова лока, то где гарантии, что при добавлении новых локов, какой-то из старых наконец разблокируется?

Comment: @I.S.M., как говорится, хороший вопрос. Насколько помню `pthread_...` не определено, зависит от реализации. При желании можете посмотреть одну из них -- http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread  А вот `Как строится очередь доступа через нескольких exclusive_lock...`, извините, не понял. Поток всегда может находится только в одной очереди ожидания. Если он при этом владеет какими-то ресурсами, то возможен deadlock. В зависимости от параметров мьютекса (по крайней мере в pthreads) эта ситуация может быть распознана системой и тогда в ответ на запрос лока получите ответ `EDEADLK`

Comment: Это я просто переформулировал вопрос. Имелась ввиду очередность разблокировки заблокированных. Все сводится к проблеме голодания некоторых потоков, deadlock-ов при этом нет. Т.е. новые потоки блокируются, нет гарантии, что старый тоже разблокируется. Впрочем, это может зависеть от реализации. Я перезадал этот вопрос недавно... Может кто-то предлагал решение.

Comment: @I.S.M.,  Очевидно, что в разных системах  по разному. Для musl  коротенько глянул сорсы, похоже, что ожидающий ресурса поток отправляют спать. Насколько? Надо изучать код функций (в т.ч. инициализацию `pthread_rwlock_t` и т.п).  Описание относящихся к делу типов вроде бы в  root/include/alltypes.h.in root/src/internal/pthread_impl.h  Если в самом деле нужно, то внимательно читайте сорсы

Comment: @I.S.M., вроде бы в вопросе вы интересовались приоритетами в locks. В принципе, linux позволяет реализацию подобных идей на user уровне. Можете поизучать [man 2 futex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) (обратите внимание на раздел Priority-inheritance futexes)

Answer (score 0):

Имхо, задачи разделения приоритетов должны решаться через соответствующие функции диспетчеризации ОС. Если поток писателя должен иметь больший приоритет, надо ему просто его предоставить, а не городить свой диспетчер поверх. Как я понимаю, здесь нужно получить [`native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) от `std::thread` и дальше вызывать зависимые от ОС функции установки приоритетов. [`pthread_setschedparam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) для POSIX совместимых ОС и [`SetThreadPriority`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx) для Windows.

Comment: В задаче имеет место дерево потоков, в котором нижележащий узел-поток является писателем для вышележащих (корни снизу). Поэтому при добавении нового узла-потока в систему придется все занижать и занижать приоритеты. А это не совсем корректно, т.к. по выполнимости эти потоки равноправны. Здесь нужно только подавлять попытки чтения вышележащими узлами ресурса.

Answer (score 0):

[boost::shared_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) использует алгоритм Терехова. В чем он заключается - не знаю, но утверждается, что никаких приоритетов не используется, какой поток будет выполниться следующим - решает ОС (видимо, на основе обычного поведения  своего диспетчера потоков).

А идея дать писателям более высокий приоритет изначально плоха, так как голодание читателей ничуть не лучше голодания писателей.

Comment: В системе присутствует 1 писатель и много читателей. При этом, на основе анализа скорости обработки ресурсов, могу сказать, что обращение читателей к ресурсу будет происходить намного чаще, чем требование ресурса писателем. Плюс к этому отсутствие приоритета не дает мне понять, каким образом читатели, получающие доступ в шахматном порядке, хоть когда-нибудь освободят ресурс.

Comment: @I.S.M. Имеется ввиду, что приоритеты не задаются вручную. ОС владеет всей информацией о потоках и может определить, что какой-то поток долго простаивает на shared_mutex, и дать ему более высокий приоритет при захвате мьютекса. Кроме того, ОС может учитывать собственные приоритеты потоков. Динамическое изменение приоритетов для диспетчера потоков - это вообще основной механизм борьбы с голоданием, мьютекс просто добавляет некоторые особенности. В частности, возникает вопрос, при каких именно условиях менять приоритеты. Нужен некоторый эвристический алгоритм.